# checkbox event not firing when checkbox is checked and it works for uncheck checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

```
  <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phShowMonsterSourceFacet" EnableViewState="true">
   <div class="oneSearchFilter">
        <div>
            <div class="filterItem chkMonsJobs">
             <asp:CheckBox ID="chkMonsJobs" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Checked="true" EnableViewState="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled" OnCheckedChanged="ChkMonsJobs_CheckedChanged"  CssClass="MNSColumnTextViewMore" /> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </asp:PlaceHolder> 

public event EventHandler RefineSearchtrivoxMonsJobCheckBoxChecked;


    protected void ChkMonsJobs_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (RefineSearchtrivoxMonsJobCheckBoxChecked != null)
        {
            RefineSearchtrivoxMonsJobCheckBoxChecked(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

check box event is triggered only when check box is unchecked the other way is not working..

Comment: What is `RefineSearchtrivoxMonsJobCheckBoxChecked`

Comment: it's an event updated the post.

Comment: It works fine for me if EnableViewState="true", It fires both the check or uncheck

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the behavior that you report, I had to set :

`EnableViewState="false"`

at the page level (or on a container of the CheckBox). If you set:

`EnableViewState="true"`

everywhere, it works for both check and uncheck actions.

An even simpler solution is to remove all EnableViewState and ViewStateMode attributes from your markup and use the default values.

UPDATE

If you want to disable the ViewState at the page level and enable it for individual controls, you can set this at the page level:

```
ViewStateMode="Disabled"
```

And this for each control that needs the ViewState:

```
ViewStateMode="Enabled"
```

In that case, you should not use EnableViewState in the markup, since using both attributes can make things more confusing...

Comment: I have tried this not working I set page level Enableviewstate to false and control container and control to true... I updated the post pls have a look.

Comment: At the page level, you set it to true or false? I must be true everywhere. Sorry, my original answer was not written clearly...

Comment: I tested it and it works both ways. So I think @ConnorsFan answer is right.

Comment: yes @ConnorsFan is correct, but without enabling the view state on page level I need to fire the checkbox event for both check and uncheck.

Comment: I updated my answer to allow you to disable the ViewState at the page level and enable it for the CheckBox.